# Unable to Unzip An uploaded file in Amazon Linux AMI

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, unzip, amazon-ami

I'm trying to unzip a file I uploaded to an Amazon Linux AMI and  Amazon Linux 2 AMI . I keep getting this error-

> End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
>   a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
>   latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
>   the last disk(s) of this archive. unzip:  cannot find zipfile
>   directory in one of sendy.zip or
>           sendy.zip.zip, and cannot find sendy.zip.ZIP, period.

I compressed the contents of the directory on my mac by right clicking the folder and clicking compress. I then uploaded the zip file to github and used the command:

```
wget https://github.com/crownofqueen/sendy2/blob/master/sendy.zip
```

to upload the zip file to the server.

I have not had any issues when using digital ocean/Linode/etc.

The contents of the files are HTML documents.

Answer (score -1):

The URL you are using with `wget` is pointing to an HTML page.

On that page you will find a Download link. You should `wget` from that download link:

```
https://github.com/crownofqueen/sendy2/raw/master/sendy.zip
```

Note that it includes *raw* in the URL. That means it is the contents of the file, as opposed to a web page that shows the file.